# Updated Field Record from Codeigniter database table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a MsUser table consist of 4 fields i.e. Id, Name, Address, and date-of-birth. Every update process, one or more fields can be updated simultaneously. I want to track the change every update.

Example: the updated fields are address and date-of-birth. System will show
"Address and date-of-birth are updated".

From that case, how should i build the edit function in model to track the updated field each update?

I have no idea how to check the changed fields from user's input. Because if i have to loop and check each field, i think it costs too much effort for the system process.

Thank you for your helps :)

Comment: when should system will show *Address and date-of-birth are updated*? any particular action?

Comment: The system will show "Address and date-of-birth are updated" after the update process/button is clicked.

Comment: basically you have to check each string with previous string and then you have to display message.

Comment: @PathikVejani here is my code in model for updating my msuser table. http://codepad.org/avU2JiOq

Comment: @PathikVejani So there is no other option except checking each field text by text?

Comment: before updating data with the new one.. you have to check that which records are going to be updated and then you can show msg accordingly.

Comment: no.. you have to do this text by text checking

Comment: @PathikVejani okay. i understand. thank you for your help.

Comment: Well I'd say there is another possibility. As you have a single update function it has to somehow know that some fields should not be updated with empty value. You could add some if statements to the same functionality ( if value is not empty add whatever field name to a string and present that in the update message).

Comment: You don't need to limit this to be in the PHP code.  You can set up a trigger in the database which can write to an audit table and store the old and new values.

Comment: @Martin So it is better to send only changed value in user's interface to the server? So the server can validate the variable is set or unset. Am i right?

Comment: @gabe3886 Thank you for your help. yes, it can be triggered to write to an audit table. but the update function received every fields as parameters. All the fields value will be saved as change in the audit table even if the value is not changed. Am i right ?

Comment: Yes I would follow that logic. Because you will have to have this functionality anyway if you want to save resorces. Overwriting an exisitng field with the same value is pointless. And if you add the check functionality before the query you will not have to have another query to check if any field was updated seperately.

Comment: @HendraHalim You can set the trigger to check the old value against the new value and save only the changed fields

Answer (score 0):

You have the `$this->input->post()` if I'm not mistaken. If you foreach the post and check each key of the array which has a value you can see what has been changed. Small idea of achieving this would be:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($this->input->post() as $field){
    if(count($this->input->post()) == $count):
        $updatedFields .= $field.", ";
    else:
        $updatedFields .= $field;
    endif;
    $count++;
}
$updatedFields .= " have been updated.";
echo $updatedFields;
```

This would output:

`username, date-of-birth have been updated.`

Comment: From your code, i assumed that only the new values are sent to the server from the user's interface. So in the server, your code can define the message. Is it right ?

Comment: Yes, this is indeed expecting only the data that needs updating.